# what is the meaning of percent symbol(%) and sharp symbol(#) in c++ template

Tags: c++, templates

here is the code from MS VC stl:

```
 template<typename _Fun_t,
    typename _Arg_t> inline
    binder1st<_Fun_t> bind1st(_Fun_t% _Func, _Arg_t _Left)
    {   // return a binder1st functor adapter
    typename _Fun_t::first_argument_type _Val = _Left;

    return (binder1st<_Fun_t>(_Func, _Val));
    }
```

and QT:

```
 #define Q_ARG(type, data) QArgument<type >(#type, data)
```

Comment: If you look closer, you will see that the hash `#` is not in a template, but in a macro, where it's the stringify operator (it makes a string of the macro argument). The percentage must be some error, because it's not valid at that place. Maybe URL encoding/decoding gone wrong?

Comment: % is [Tracking Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a%28VS.80%29.aspx) - speciality of .NET

Comment: so what's the Q_ARG(type, data) unwound expression?

Comment: Of course, in a "STL" (Standard Library) header, you may find code that is specific to your compiler. The _interface_ is portable, but the implementation might not be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither of these is specific to templates.

The '%' is a Microsoft extension to C++, part of C++/CLI.  It defines a tracking reference.  A normal lvalue reference variable of type `T&` is a reference to another variable; so is `T%` except it refers to a managed object which might be moved by the garbage collector; the GC knows that when it moves objects it has to patch up all the tracking references to that object.

'#' is the stringify operator of the C preprocessor.  It means the value of the following macro argument, surrounded by double quote marks.  So this:

```
Q_ARG(MyType, 12345)
```

will expand to this:

```
QArgument<MyType >("MyType", 12345);
```